# Programmatically Backup database from host in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, backup, plesk

I have a website and an SQL Server database on it. The control panel of my host is Plesk 12.5. Now, I want backup my database and store it on a special folder in my host. I've added permisson to save data to this special folder in my host control panel, and the function that I use it to create and save database backup is :

```
    string CS = "server=localhost;database = Test;uid=***; password=***;";
    string filename = "testDB.bak";

    string folderPath = Server.MapPath("~/Backups/");
    if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        string SqlStmt = String.Format("Backup Database Test To Disk = '{0}'", folderPath + filename);
        using (SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(SqlStmt, con))
        {
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception E)
            {
                Label1.Text = E.Message;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

'Backups' folder is created, but for backup, get this error: "Cannot open backup device 'C:***********.com\httpdocs\Backups\testDB.bak'. Operating system error 5(Access is denied.). BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally."

Comment: The "Access is denied" text suggests that the folder is either read only or lacks the security authorization for your account to perform a write to this folder. Have you checked the folder's properties about these two attributes?

Comment: @JohnH yes. for test and check it, I set Full Control to all users.